# Special name for $k!\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$

Tags: convention

$$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$ The expression above is also known as binomial coefficient. Is there a similar naming convention that describes the one below? $$k!\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$$

Comment: It's sometimes referred to as $P^n_k$, the permutation of $k$ objects from a given group of $n$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\displaystyle \frac{n!}{(n-k)!} = k!\binom{n}{k} = n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots (n-k+1)$ is the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials).

Comment: It is sometimes denoted $n^{\underline k}$ to illustrate the parallels with exponentiation (instead of multiplying k copies of n, it is k shifted copies)

Answer (score 1):

If the choose function is defined as:
$$C(n,r)=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$$
And the permutation function is defined as:
$$P(n,r)=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$$
then you are looking at the permutation function

Comment: https://www.mathplanet.com/education/algebra-2/discrete-mathematics-and-probability/permutations-and-combinations

Comment: http://www.probabilityformula.org/Permutations.html